# How to query the memory pool?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, rpc, txpool

Block explorer [explorer.xmr.my](https://explorer.xmr.my) shows the contents of the memory pool. Does `monerod`, `monero-wallet-cli` or another CLI utility allow to query the Monero's memory pool? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

monerod has a `get_transaction_pool` RPC call:

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/get_transaction_pool -d '{}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

This will return the current state of the tx pool. Each transaction in the pool has this information:

`std::string id_hash;
    std::string tx_json; // TODO - expose this data directly
    uint64_t blob_size;
    uint64_t fee;
    std::string max_used_block_id_hash;
    uint64_t max_used_block_height;
    bool kept_by_block;
    uint64_t last_failed_height;
    std::string last_failed_id_hash;
    uint64_t receive_time;
    bool relayed;
    uint64_t last_relayed_time;`

monero-wallet-cli has a `get_transfers` RPC call. This can be configured to return transactions in the pool going to the wallet, by setting "pool" to true:

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:1234/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_transfers","params":{"in":false,"out":true,"pending":false,"failed":false,"pool":true,"min_height":735000,"max_height":1000000,"filter_by_height":true}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

This will return this information for every transaction:

`std::string txid;
      std::string payment_id;
      uint64_t height;
      uint64_t timestamp;
      uint64_t amount;
      uint64_t fee;
      std::string note;
      std::list<transfer_destination> destinations;`

Note that some information may or may not be present. For example, destinations is not known for incoming transactions (sush as those incoming transactions found in the pool).