# Why would a candidate transfer be sitting in the memory pool after 3 days?

Tags: block-explorer, txpool

Block explorer [explorer.xmr.my](https://explorer.xmr.my) currently shows a transaction in the memory pool with "Age 76:18:00", that is more than 3 days.

[image]

Assuming the information shown is accurate, I am wondering why it wouldn't be included in a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the 56c5e5f2a7f6ab97a0c589731278a7d4ef0516484cde1376e213b5b160af548b tx hash at each of the other block explorers mentioned in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/538/number-of-monero-block-explorers-and-their-unique-features) with the following results:

Moneroblocks

> Uh-oh Shame on you! There is no such thing as 56c5e5f2a7f6ab97a0c589731278a7d4ef0516484cde1376e213b5b160af548b in Monero's blockchain!

Chain Radar

> Not Found (#404) Unable to resolve the request "xmr/search/ 56c5e5f2a7f6ab97a0c589731278a7d4ef0516484cde1376e213b5b160af548b".

Onion Monero Blockchain Explorer

> Search results for: 56c5e5f2a7f6ab97a0c589731278a7d4ef0516484cde1376e213b5b160af548b
>   Nothing in the blockchain has been found that matches the search term :-(

Monero Explorer currently displays a message at the top of its screen

> Info! We are updating the site with new features, some function are temporarily disabled.

The payment ID contained in the tx hash you found has been used in over [2,000 transactions](http://moneroblocks.info/search/4be146fb0f8691b6b9094768194944a88c5bc47b6dbf874e6b417459f924b895). These factors point to a possibility that this issue could be an error related to testing of the feature updates now being conducted by that particular block explorer.

Comment: Meanwhile, the weird entry is gone there. Like you suggested at the end of your answer, I now also think that it was some kind of glitch (or testing). Yesterday, when it was still shown, I couldn't see the transaction hash in the output of the `get_transaction_pool` RPC call as described in [this question](http://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2734/280).